# the " popup.style.display= 'flex'; " line is not getting executed. showing error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, html

```
function updateWrongLettersE1(){
    // Display wrong letters
    wrorgLettersE1.innerHTML = `
    ${wrongLetters.length > 0 ? '<p>Wrong</p>' : ''}
    ${wrongLetters.map(letter => `<span>${letter}</span>`)}
    `;

    // Display parts
    figureParts.forEach((part,index) => {
        const errors = wrongLetters.length;

        if(index < errors) {
            part.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            part.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    // Check if lost
    if(wrongLetters.length === figureParts.length){
        finalMessage.innerText = 'Unfortunately you Lost.';
        popup.style.display= 'flex';
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that `popup` is `null`.

Comment: I have defined this line before

Comment: const popup = document.getElementById('popup-container');

Comment: That is good, however the error still means what it means. Did you `console.log(popup)` to verify that the element was found?